# A way to implement CultureInfo in string[] to float[] Converter<>

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, floating-point

I am looking for a way to add `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in my string[] to float[] converter.
I use this code, but it keeps throwing

> Input string was not in a correct format.
>   exceptions.

This is the code:

```
clearList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, float[]>(fileNamesList[i].Item1, fileNamesList[i].Item2, Array.ConvertAll(fileNamesList[i].Item3, new Converter<string, float>(float.Parse))));
```

UPDATE:

```
        static List<Tuple<string, string, string[]>> fileNamesList = new List<Tuple<string, string, string[]>>();
       static List<Tuple<string, string, float[]>> clearList = new List<Tuple<string, string, float[]>>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < fileNamesList.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < fileNamesList[i].Item3.Count(); j++)
            {                    
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileNamesList[i].Item3[j]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Empty");
                }
                else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileNamesList[i].Item3[j]))
                {

                    if (fileNamesList[i].Item1.Equals("INCLUDE"))
                    {

                        string dataType = fileNamesList[i].Item1;
                        string date = fileNamesList[i].Item2;

                        string[] fileContent = fileNamesList[i].Item3;
                        clearList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, float[]>(dataType, date, Array.ConvertAll(fileContent, new Converter<string, float>(float.Parse))));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please provide a mvce/

Comment: I want to convert a string array to a float array, but it keeps throwing: Input string was not in a correct format. exceptions.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Verifiable, Complete Example. Also stop putting that many operations into one line. The only price for saving line is not being able to debug. Make a bunch of temporary variables taking one operation result each, so you know wich of those 5 or so operations even throws the exception. The JiT can take care of cutting them out in release builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just replace the

- float.Parse

with

- s => float.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < fileNamesList.Count; i++)
  {
      for (int j = 0; j < fileNamesList[i].Item3.Count(); j++)
      {
          if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileNamesList[i].Item3[j]))
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Empty");
          }
          else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileNamesList[i].Item3[j]))
          {

              if (fileNamesList[i].Item1.Equals("INCLUDE"))
              {

                  string dataType = fileNamesList[i].Item1;
                  string date = fileNamesList[i].Item2;

                  string[] fileContent = fileNamesList[i].Item3;
                  clearList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, float[]>(dataType, date, Array.ConvertAll(fileContent, new Converter<string, float>(s => float.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture )))));
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: It is not working, Error CS0305 Using the generic type 'Converter<TInput, TOutput>' requires 2 type arguments

Comment: @IvanZlatanov: That is why he proposes calling Parse directly. Rather then have convert call it for you.

Comment: I replaced sample data in your code and it works.
is there anything different in your real code?

List<Tuple<string, string, float[]>> clearList = new List<Tuple<string, string, float[]>>();
clearList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, float[]>("1.3", "2.4", Array.ConvertAll(new[] { "1.1", "2.2" }, new Converter<string, float>(s => float.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))));

Comment: @Christopher Thanks, I found that the problem is coming from another source. Sorry for bothering you!